# Explanation and example for use of ackExpression in Until Successful Scope

Tags: mule

I am trying to understand the use of Until Successful Scope but am consfused with the use of ackExpression attribute, the documentation has precious little on it [here](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Until+Successful+Scope)

> Specifies an expression that, when evaluated to true, determines the
>   synchronous response of until-successful.

The blog [here](http://blogs.mulesoft.org/meet-until-successful-store-and-forward-for-mule/) also has a couple of lines on it, but I have not been able to make sense of it, would appreciate a example and usecase for the attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`until-successful` default operation mode is asynchronous. The `ackExpression` allows you to synchronously produce a response payload to the inbound event.

Comment: So the synchronous attribute and ackepression are mutually exclusive then ?

Comment: Yes, it would make no sense to use `ackExpression` in `synchronous` mode.